# How can I get selection text from an iframe that generated by a rich text editor

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I want to get the selection text from evernote's rich text editor, but failed.

The approach I tried:

### 1. define a contentscript in manifest.json that `"all_frame": true`

Failed because contentscript not load in a dynamic generated iframe that without a url.

### 2. iterate over iframes in page and the one that has its document.body `contenteditable="true"`

Failed because the following error.

> Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.evernote.com" from accessing a frame with origin "chrome-extension://oknpjjbmpnndlpmnhmekjpocelpnlfdi".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "chrome-extension". Protocols must match.

**The origin and protocol not match.**

---

Is there any other way to go? Please help me.

Comment: You have to inject the part of the code that accesses the iframe into the target page's scope.  The injected code would use messages (best), local storage, or global variables to exchange data back with the content script.